# C++ Printing Odd numbers instead of Prime Numbers

Tags: c++, primes

I have been working on an assignment question for days and cannot seem to get the correct output (I've tried so many things!) The question is:

Write a program that uses two nested for loops and the modulus operator (%) to detect and print the prime numbers from 1 to 10,000.

I have been doing from 1 to 10 as a small test to ensure its working. I am getting 2,3,5,7,9 as my output, so I know something is wrong. When I increase the number from 10 to 20 it is printing 2 plus all odd numbers. I am including my code below. Thanks!!

```
int main() {

        for (int i=2; i <=10; i++){
            for (int j=2; j<=i; j++){
                if (i%j==0 && j!=i) {

                    break;    
                }

                else { 

                    cout<< i <<endl;
                    break;
                }           
            }   
        }
}
```

Comment: You may not realize that you are breaking out of your loop on the first iteration no matter what.

Comment: @perreal - not quite; see for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: What might also help you is to split the problem - first create a function bool isPrime(int x) and call that in the outer loop. This will help you separate the i and j and better debug the problem.

Comment: @perreal I mean that your statement "it is not possible to decide that a number is prime until you try all possible numbers that can divide that number" is not quite accurate. For example, 2, 3, 4 and 6 all divide 12 but I don't need to test *all* of those to determine that 12 is not prime. I also meant to say, that there are better ways to test for primality than naively dividing by all numbers from 2 to sqrt(n).

Comment: @perreal not quite sure what you mean. But just to pick one point; except for 2 you *don't* ever need to test even numbers as they won't be prime, also, [only numbers that +/-1 are divisible by 6 can possibly be prime](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html), which can also help narrow the scope of what to test.. and there are *many* more ways to narrow the scope.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Sumit Jindal's answer inner for loop can be done by this way as well:

```
for(int j=2; j*j<=i ; j++)
```

If we think about every (x,y) ordered pair that satisfies x*y = i, maximum value of x can be square root of i.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the if-else branch. Your inner loop will be run exactly once because it will break out of the inner loop as a result of your if else branch.

When you first enter the inner loop the value of *j is 2*. Your condition will test if *variable i* is divisible by 2. If it is it breaks. Other wise (your else branch) will print the value of *i* and breaks out. 
Hence printing odd numbers.

Break out of the inner loop and check whether *j equals i* in outer loop. You have to make *j* available for outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is within the inner loop, and it should not be - it's only a prime if you run all the way through the inner loop without finding a divisor.

As a second point, you only need to check for divisors up to the square root of i, not all the way up to i.

Comment: It's fine to put the print statement within the inner loop if it is followed by a break statement, *and* you have logic to ensure that this is only executed after the inner loop has run far enough to determine that the number is prime. The OP's code only fulfils one of those things.

Comment: @DavidScarlett: well yes, that does amount tot the same thing, but it would be a rather complex loop termination ...

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the inner loop after the first iteration itself, which is checking if the number(ie **i**) is different from **j** and is  divisible by 2 or not (since **j=2** for the first iteration)

> I am getting 2,3,5,7,9 as my output

This is because every odd number fails the **if** and is printed in **else** condition

Answer (score 0):

A minor correction in your code, adding a flag. Also you don't need to run the inner loop i times, infact only i/2 times is sufficient. This is simple mathematics, but will save significant number of CPU cycles (~5000 iterations lesser in your case)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++){
        bool isPrime = true;
        for(int j=2; j<=i/2; j++){
            if(i!=j && i%j==0){
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime)
            std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did try adding flags in earlier versions but I was still breaking the loop in the wrong spot. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Another version, if you don't mind output in reverse order.

```
int n = 10;

for (int i = n; i > 1; --i)
{
    int factorCount = 0;
    for (int j = 2; j <= n; ++j)
    {
        if (i % j == 0)
            factorCount++;

        if (factorCount > 1)
            break;
    }
    if (factorCount == 1)
        cout << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int main() { 

    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i%j == 0)
                break;

            if (j==i-1) // means has never run previous if blog
                cout << i << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```